# Syntactic Sugar to check null in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-2

Is there any better way to code razor cshtml that checks for null for nested object so it wont throw null exception error on the container object if the container is null. For example :

**page.cshtml**

```
Hello @obj1.obj2.prop3
```

will throw error if obj1 is null or obj1.prop3is null, but

```
Hello @Html.DisplayFor(m => obj1.obj2.prop3)
```

can check for null on obj1 or obj1.obj2 so it won't throw error

```
Hello @(obj1 == null? "" : (obj1.obj2 == null? "" : obj1.obj2.prop3))
```

is just too lengthy

Comment: Consider not passing null as properties in model - often it is possible to have "empty" objects (empty string/default values for all non-ref properties) that let you avoid all these null checks...

Comment: I think thats allready pretty short for what you are trying to accomplish;) You have the ?? operator but that won't work in your case since you need to access more properties. (Obj ?? "" gives the obj or if null "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating your own html helper:

```
static class MyOwnHtmlHelpers
{
    public static string EmptyIfNull<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Func<TModel, string> accessor)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = accessor.Invoke(helper.ViewData.Model);
            return result;
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
@Html.EmptyIfNull(m => obj1.obj2.prop3)
```